# How to use typescript for client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been using typescript + eslint successfully for node.js. But now when I try to use it for regular client side javascript, I get this

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'alert'.
```

when I try to do a basic `alert(1);`.

How can I get it to recognize regular javascript types? Do I need to install something further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you should check you tsconfig.json, where you should have dom library

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
  ...
}
```